# Lightsail Django app + GoDaddy hosting - possible to use Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I'm running Django APP on AWS Lightsail under GoDaddy hosting - I have generated Let's encrypt SSL keys, but got nowhere to place them, no access to CPanel at all.

Is it possible to connect them somehow or I can only buy paid SSL from GoDaddy?

Comment: You don't need payed SSL cert.  Have you registered your domain with the lets encrypt ssl?

Comment: I did, but I can not access CPanel (no such option) and don't know where to put the codes at all